# Specify Poetry install with if inside Dockerfile

Tags: python, dockerfile, python-poetry, python-3.10

I'm building from a Python 3.10.12-slim-bullseye image, and got everything working for my production Dockerfile, I'm using Poetry so I run:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR poetry install --without dev --no-root
```

This works fine, but now I wanted to add the option of having an argument for when I'm working in development, so it may also install extra dependencies through `--all-extras` like this:

```
ARG DEV=false
RUN if [ $DEV = "true" ] ; \
    then --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR poetry install --all-extras --no-root ; \
    else --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR poetry install --without dev --no-root ; \
    fi
```

However, now this won't run and I get a generic failed to solve: process ... did not complete successfully: exit code: 127. Any ideas on how to run the different commands?

Comment: try wrapping your `if [ $ DEV....` with `bash -c "f [ $ DEV..."`

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me, inspired by the answer by sudden_appearance, was to wrap the if statement with the cache statement, instead of running it inside of the `if` statement itself, that is:

```
ARG DEV=false
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$POETRY_CACHE_DIR \
    if [ $DEV = "true" ] ; \
    then poetry install --all-extras --no-root ; \
    else poetry install --without dev --no-root ; \
    fi
```